# 401 response Twitter reverse auth

Tags: twitter-oauth

Here is the authorization header I use:

```
Authorization = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"2D9rLD8Lu23hrchrh4VMBkQ6AZKHYi2yY2oeuoeutcFMdAs\", oauth_nonce=\"-486353546\", oauth_signature="x3NdGnJmBTUAICBRE9C44N8mFd4%3D", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"137663828056\", oauth_version=\"1.0\", x_auth_mode=\"reverse_auth\"";
```

Here's the base string I use:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
```

Here's the [twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) I'm working from:

> Step 1: Obtain a Special Request Token
>
> First, you make an HTTPS request to the Twitter Request Token URL
>   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token with your application's
>   consumer key. In addition to the conventional oauth_* signing
>   parameters, you must also include x_auth_mode set to the value
>   reverse_auth.
>
> As an example, consider a request with the following values signed
>   with the token secret ydC2yUbFaScbSlykO0PmrMjXFeLraSi3Q2HfTOlGxQM:
>
> The tokens used here are for demonstration purposes only, and will not
>   work for you.
>
> oauth_consumer_key JP3PyvG67rXRsnayOJOcQ oauth_nonce
>   1B7D865D-9E15-4ADD-8165-EF90D7A7D3D2 oauth_signature_method HMAC-SHA1
>   oauth_timestamp 1322697052 oauth_version 1.0 x_auth_mode reverse_auth
>   These parameters should result in a signature base string that looks
>   like this:
>
> POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_consumer_key%3DJP3PyvG67rXRsnayOJOcQ%26oauth_nonce%3D1B7D865D-9E15-4ADD-8165-EF90D7A7D3D2%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1322697052%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26x_auth_mode%3Dreverse_auth
>   This call should result in a response that looks like this. Notice
>   that this response actually looks like an OAuth header.
>
> (line wrapping added for clarity):
>
> OAuth oauth_nonce="xq2maKtilFhVTC1MSxVC4cQIJLd53O6w97YmrdOGSk8", 
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",  oauth_timestamp="1322697052", 
>   oauth_consumer_key="JP3PyvG67rXRsnayOJOcQ", 
>   oauth_token="5mgkU82W0PTA0DLgSIA5vFK6c08i8dXzrbLnX06vl38", 
>   oauth_signature="aOM%2FwW2kAowAeHBRvw7faH245p0%3D", 
>   oauth_version="1.0"

**Edit**: I still get a `401`. I used the following code to generate the `oauth_signature`, so now my Authorization header looks like this: `OAuth oauth_timestamp="1376639141", oauth_nonce="BB2D2634F3-99A5-4B64-8CB34E-2314CE9E4FD7", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_consumer_key="mrcD8LuSNKJKFAchKHYi2yY2qwh5tcFMdAs", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="moer8H7xzluAdoAAAFZpv6n4noeu%3D"`

```
NSString *OAuthorizationHeader(NSURL *url, NSString *method, NSData *body, NSString *_oAuthConsumerKey, NSString *_oAuthConsumerSecret, NSString *_oAuthToken, NSString *_oAuthTokenSecret)
{
    NSString *_oAuthNonce = [NSString ab_GUID];
    NSString *_oAuthTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSString *_oAuthSignatureMethod = @"HMAC-SHA1";
    NSString *_oAuthVersion = @"1.0";

    NSMutableDictionary *oAuthAuthorizationParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    oAuthAuthorizationParameters[@"oauth_nonce"] = _oAuthNonce;
    oAuthAuthorizationParameters[@"oauth_timestamp"] = _oAuthTimestamp;
    oAuthAuthorizationParameters[@"oauth_signature_method"] = _oAuthSignatureMethod;
    oAuthAuthorizationParameters[@"oauth_version"] = _oAuthVersion;
    oAuthAuthorizationParameters[@"oauth_consumer_key"] = _oAuthConsumerKey;
    if(_oAuthToken)
        oAuthAuthorizationParameters[@"oauth_token"] = _oAuthToken;

    // get query and body parameters
    NSDictionary *additionalQueryParameters = [NSURL ab_parseURLQueryString:[url query]];
    NSDictionary *additionalBodyParameters = nil;
    if(body) {
        NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        if(string) {
            additionalBodyParameters = [NSURL ab_parseURLQueryString:string];
        }
    }

    // combine all parameters
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[oAuthAuthorizationParameters mutableCopy] autorelease];
    if(additionalQueryParameters) [parameters addEntriesFromDictionary:additionalQueryParameters];
    if(additionalBodyParameters) [parameters addEntriesFromDictionary:additionalBodyParameters];

    // -> UTF-8 -> RFC3986
    NSMutableDictionary *encodedParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for(NSString *key in parameters) {
        NSString *value = parameters[key];
        encodedParameters[[key ab_RFC3986EncodedString]] = [value ab_RFC3986EncodedString];
    }

    NSArray *sortedKeys = [[encodedParameters allKeys] sortedArrayUsingFunction:SortParameter context:encodedParameters];

    NSMutableArray *parameterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
        [parameterArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, encodedParameters[key]]];
    }
    NSString *normalizedParameterString = [parameterArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];

    NSString *normalizedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@%@", [url scheme], [url host], [url path]];

    NSString *signatureBaseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@&%@",
                                     [method ab_RFC3986EncodedString],
                                     [normalizedURLString ab_RFC3986EncodedString],
                                     [normalizedParameterString ab_RFC3986EncodedString]];

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@",
                     [_oAuthConsumerSecret ab_RFC3986EncodedString],
                     (_oAuthTokenSecret) ? [_oAuthTokenSecret ab_RFC3986EncodedString] : @""];

    NSData *signature = HMAC_SHA1(signatureBaseString, key);
    NSString *base64Signature = [signature base64EncodedString];

    NSMutableDictionary *authorizationHeaderDictionary = [[oAuthAuthorizationParameters mutableCopy] autorelease];
    authorizationHeaderDictionary[@"oauth_signature"] = base64Signature;

    NSMutableArray *authorizationHeaderItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSString *key in authorizationHeaderDictionary) {
        NSString *value = authorizationHeaderDictionary[key];
        [authorizationHeaderItems addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"",
                                             [key ab_RFC3986EncodedString],
                                             [value ab_RFC3986EncodedString]]];
    }

    NSString *authorizationHeaderString = [authorizationHeaderItems componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

    authorizationHeaderString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth %@", authorizationHeaderString];

    return authorizationHeaderString;
}
```

The parameters I pass in to this method are
`url`: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, `method`: POST, `body`: nil, `oAuthConsumerToken`: my key, `oAuthConsumerSecret`: my secret, `oAuthToken`:nil,`oAuthTokenSecret`:nil.

**EDIT** I tried this [oauth test console](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console) to verify that I'm properly generating the oauth signature, but it appears I need the Member's token and secret:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the oauth_signature in the Authorization header.

Comment: It appears that I don't need the `oauth_signature` in the Authorization header. It looks like that should be part of the response.

Comment: The documentation states that you should be 'familiar with the signing process before you attempt to use the endpoint' which suggests your initial request still needs to be signed. Also why would you produce a signature base string if you are not going to sign the request?

Comment: Thanks, I added it and I still get a 401. I'm writing up how I generated the signature at the end of my question.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Objective-C so I can't comment on your code, however you can check your generated signature using a tool such as [this one from LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console).

Comment: Sure, but if you're nervous about using your actual keys and secrets you could generate fake ones and use the signature output to check against the one generated from your code with the same input. If they produce the same signature you'll know the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: That site requires a member token and secret. I'm trying to sign in a user to get their token and secret. Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: You do not need to enter a member token and secret in order for the test console to generate a signature. Enter your consumer key, consumer secret, nonce and timestamp into the relevant boxes and leave Member Token and Member Secret blank. Set the URL to 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', the HTTP Verb to POST and enter 'x_auth_mode=reverse_auth' into the Query Parameters. Click 'Generate Signed URL' and it will display the signature base string, signature and Authorization header.

Comment: It appears I do need the member token and secret. See the addition to my question.

Comment: You have to remove the text "The Member's Token" and "The Member's Secret" so the boxes are blank. I also notice that you have missed the "https://" off the front of the URL, your HTTP Verb should be "POST" and Query Parameters should be "x_auth_mode=reverse_auth".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35824/discussion-between-jonny-s-and-rose-perrone)